# Learning Objective-C as a first language

Tags: objective-c

Do you think that its a good practice to learn Objective-C as a first language/library, or should I just jump back a little and start learning in another C type language?

I've been self-learning Objective-C for about 4 months now. I absolutely love it, my friends and family also support it as well.

So, what do people here think about Objective-C as a first language to learn? Is it worth it to continue with my work with Objective-C?

Comment: I think it's a lousy idea.  Much better to learn another language (eg, Java) first, and become proficient before jumping into Objective-C.  But others have different opinions.

Comment: I think it's a fine idea. That's what I pretty much did. Objective-C is pretty easy to learn, however it makes it a lot harder to merge into other languages.

Comment: I think it would make a great first language, provided you're on an Apple platform and have access to their libraries. The libraries' verbosity makes it clear what functions and methods do what, and make it extremely readable. There is enough dynamism in the language that there's not as much red tape, but the compiler still will keep you from going too far off in the weeds sometimes. Downside is that you will have to learn basic programming as well as more advanced beginner / intermediate Object Oriented concepts simultaneously. However, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow :)

Comment: "Another C type language?" Why not simply master C itself? Objective-C is a strict superset of C; it effectively is C with a layer of object-oriented extensions.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses!!!

Comment: I suggest to learn C basics first.

Comment: http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Objective-C can be a fine first language, particularly if you're interested in doing Mobile programming. I wouldn't necessarily recommend switching to learn a different language, but if you really want to learn how to program I would recommend learning as many languages as you are comfortable learning. Many different languages have different ways of thinking about problems, different benefits, and different cultures, and exposing yourself to the different ways of doing things in other languages will make you better in whatever language you end up in long term.