# Precursor to learning Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, cocoa

I want to learn Objective C, but I want to do it properly. Before I start, should I learn another language first? (I was thinking C/C++).

Obviously this is quite subjective, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably C, since objective C is a subset of C

Comment: Knowing C doesn't hurt at all, it actually makes lots of things a lot clearer - there are a few places where people say "why on earth does Objective-C do it this way" where someone with knowledge of C says "of course it's done this way because of C". Lots of posts here that would be obvious if Objective-C programmers all knew C. C++ is much less important; you'll only need it if you use C++ libraries and you probably can get away with never writing C++ code yourself.

Comment: In the '80s it was a positive sales point for Objective-C that you can bring all your C knowledge with you. Nowadays it seems to evoke more of an "oh, yuck, I might have to learn some C too?" response...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning Objective-C as a first language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347849/learning-objective-c-as-a-first-language)

Comment: @awesomeyi Objective-C is a super-set of C, not subset.

Comment: @ArslanAli It sort of goes the other way too, though. Any C code is valid in Objective-C, but the C that you typically use when writing Objective-C code is a fairly small subset of C.

Comment: @Caleb Yes, you are right. You know better and more than me, I'm just a beginner in the Apple world :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest learning C because anything that is legal in C is legal in Objective C. Much of the syntax of C is passed on to Objective C (except for `@`). Pointers are very relevant in C, as they are in Objective C, so a good understanding of pointers from C is imperative. C is a procedural language though, and Objective C is Object Oriented. Languages like Java, C#, and C++ will ease you into the OO state of mind, a critical part of Objective C.

Edit: If you really want to go all out, learn Smalltalk too, as this is the language that Objective C got its messaging ideas from.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is built on top of C, it is C with some extra stuff added to it. You can write the pure C code in a .m* file, and can expect it to work and it works. So the more you know about C, the more you understand Objective-C.

For example, someone asked me how does the following line of code work in Objective-C:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello, World!"; //**
```

Basically, he was asking me that how can I assign a string literal `@"Hello, World!"` to a variable of pointer type. But if he had gone through C, there would have been no need to ask this question. Because in C, you can write the following line of code:

```
char *string = "Hello, World!";
```

It actually assigns **the pointer to char array - `"Hello, World!"` to the variable `string` that is of-course pointer type.**

Not only this, Objective-C makes heavy use of Blocks, and again blocks are a C thing. Same way, the pointers to functions, structs etc all come from C to Objective-C.

Objective-C also uses `printf` like syntax when it sends messages to console.

So, yes. Learning C first definitely helps you have a good understanding of Objective-C.

*Objective-C files are typically stored with .m extension

** We use `@` sign so that compiler could differentiate which are C strings ( with out starting with @ ) and which are objective-C strings ( with starting @ ).

Answer (score -1):

Don't learn C++ before! It might confuse you and will not help understanding Objective-C. If you want to get a feel for the object oriented part of Objective-C you should maybe look at Smalltalk. Smalltalk is great for beginners, but unfortunately there is not too much teaching material that is geared towards adults.

However I'd recommend learning Objective-C without learning anything else first. There are some books and courses that have that focus.